# How can I easily read the Apache log file?

Tags: apache-http-server, vnc, viewer

It sounds stupid, but I have issues to read my log files because my VNC window is too small. I cannot resize it, and the only way is to move the cursor or download the file and read it with a local editor I guess.

I'm using JollysFastVNC and it is an apache log file. Any tip to improve my daily debugging?

Comment: I don't quite get what the problem is? What are the issues exactly? Why are you having issues reading it?

Comment: Have you tried a different VNC viewer? UltraVNC for example is able to resize tzhe window properly

Comment: @Diskilla: UltraVNC is not working on mac, right ?

Comment: @BlodPhilia: I have issues because I can only move the cursor to right to read the end of the lines, I wish I could have a bigger window, but if I resize my window I only zoom the content and I cannot see nothing more.

Comment: I honestly don´t know if there is a Mac version of UltraVNC. You didn´t mention your OS anywhere.

Comment: @Diskilla: that's true but JollysFastVNC is only for mac, so it was implicit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not configure your webserver to map a url to your log file, then you can use a browser to browse it.

Edit your apache configuration file (depends on the operating system, and how it is setup as to where this is), and add something like:

Alias /logs /var/log/apache2

Then http://myserver/logs/access_log will display the log file. Note that the log file name might be different - again it is defined in the apache configuration file, look for the CustomLog line.

Comment: ok cool. How can I do that with Apache ??